# Does ASP.NET MVC authentication work with alternative source to database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a service which can query the database and return the user object.

I would like to implement MVC authentication in my application with the use of the above service.

Does ASP.NET MVC authentication work with out entity frame work? If yes, which class implementations should I be overriding to use the service for authentication ?

Comment: where did you plan to store the username and password information, if not a database?

Comment: With the limited information I can see, I would say no. You need a database to store the user information.

Comment: Yes, Identity can work without a database.  However, it will be limited to a deployment session.  Ever time you redeploy the previous data is lost.

Comment: google "custom asp.net identity" and you should find some helpful articles.

Comment: @Claies - I am storing the information in the database. But the requirement is not to connect to database from the application. The application has to go through wcf service and this service has access to database to get the data.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant component relationships to know about are as follows:

`SignInManager` talks to `UserManager` talks to `UserStore`

The class to override is `UserStore`. If you create an ASP.NET application from the Visual Studio templates, it will provide a user store from `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`.

You can replace this user store with your own `MyWcfServiceUserStore` (or whatever you choose to call it).

For example, if you represented the user as `MyUserType`, and it used  a `Guid` as a unique identifier:

```
 public class MyWcfServiceUserStore
    : IUserLockoutStore<MyUserType, Guid>,
      IUserPasswordStore<MyUserType, Guid>,
      IUSerTwoFactorStore<MyUserType, Guid>,
      IUserEmailStore<MyUserType, Guid>
{
   // Lots of methods to implement now
}
```

You would then modify the code so the `UserManager` is passed the `MyWcfServiceUserStore` in the constructor.

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<MyUserType, Guid>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<MyUserType, Guid> store)
       : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
       var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new MyWcfServiceUserStore(...));
       //
       // Further initialization here
       //
       return manager;
    }
}
```

While this isn't exactly trivial, it should be straightforward to implement all of the required `UserStore` methods yourself. One thing to keep in mind, within one web call the `UserManager` might hit the `UserStore` several times with identical queries, so you will have to make good use of caching.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest hack is to use form authentication, I have done it, but not in production.

LoginViewModel

```
public class LoginViewModel
     {
        [Required]
        public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel login)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "Form is not valid; please review and try again.";
            return View("Login");
        }

        if ((login.Username == "some@some.com" && login.Password == "NotVeryWise")) { 
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.Username, false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }  


        ViewBag.Error = "Credentials invalid. Please try again.";
        return View("Login");
    }
```

Web.config

```
    <system.web>
    //...
    //...
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/Home" />
    </authentication>

  </system.web>
```

You can now use [Authorize] on controllers.